# Google Analytics compare visitors of 2 different html pages on same domain

Tags: google-analytics

Sorry for the weird title but I didn't really know how to put it. What I want is a graph on Analytics that shows me how many people per day visited which site but I can't really find any option for this. This should be like this in the Android Developer Console but with the page names instead of Android versions of course:

[image]

So I can compare the amount of user per day on domain.com/a.html version domain.com/b.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to create advanced segments based off of conditions that match what you are trying to differentiate visits by. For example:

[image]

where you can select the exact page to which the segment applies. You can then select the appropriate date range that want you view the data for.

Comment: Perfect thanks great! I set both of the pages into one segment on the first try and wondered about the low stats but then I figured out you should create separate segments and that worked :D